# Accounts for Har Sinai

Tags: history, kabbalat-hatorah

How many accounts for the giving of the Torah on Har Sinai do we have in Jewish tradition?

Comment: Will you count other parts of Na"kh?

Comment: Where there any "historical written accounts" of anything of that era?

Comment: What does this question have to do with Judaism?

Comment: Does the Torah itself even count as a historical record given how it skips years and records things out of order (according to everyone who accepts Rashi)?

Comment: @DoubleAA sure, I'm looking for any additional sources

Comment: @Ephraim  I don't know, that's why I'm asking. A friend who has emunah questions is asking me, and I don't know the answers

Comment: @YEZ - it's for a friend who has Emunah questions and would help anyone with their emunah issues, if any

Comment: @Yitzchak I would say it's a historical source, as it's a document that has been passed down thousands of years. The skeptics may wonder at the skipping but they can at least agree that it says the general story of Maamad Har Sinai

Comment: I'm not a skeptic but I would argue that the skipping, and presence of all sorts of things that aren't history and many things that require trained experts to tell you whether they are meshalim or not indicate that the Torah is not really about history.

Comment: Why would a historical document have any more validity than the Torah itself?

Comment: @GershonGold Of course I don't believe in greater validity, but it's just the 'several sources' rule that this specific skeptic requested.

Comment: Shloime, it looks like this question is going to be closed as [off-topic here](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1473). If it is, do you want it migrated over to [history.se]? Maybe the experts there will have a good answer.

Comment: @msh210 OK sure

Comment: @DoubleAA Can you kindly point me to some places you had in mind?

Comment: @msh210 I actually have a fairly simple way to edit this and make it on topic - which was probably the intention of the one who asked Shloime. However, if the question is being migrated, I think it would be pointless to edit it... What to do?

Comment: @yydl, if it was Shloime's intent, then he should do it himself. You can, too. The question's had 4 of the necessary 5 closure votes for days now; if it gets a fifth, it's closed. If you edit it so it's more surely on topic, it'll unlikely get that fifth.

Comment: @msh210 if I knew how to do it, I would

Answer (score 0):

Most things weren't written down back then, plus Matan Torah happened only in front of the Jews so although the other nations knew about it, what was there to write down?

Comment: The entire world knew of this. Did anyone write anything? Did anyone write anywhere that their grandfather told them of the Sinai event?